# Cannot resolve keyword 'items' into field. Choices are: id, name

Tags: python, django, django-models, virtualenv, photologue

I am using photologue to create a photo gallery site with django. I installed django-tagging into my virtualenv, not knowing it was no longer supported by photologue. Now, after having performed migrations, whenever I try to add a photo or view the photo, I get FieldError at /admin/photologue/photo/upload_zip/
Cannot resolve keyword 'items' into field. Choices are: id, name.

I uninstalled and reinstalled django, photologue, the SQLite file, and removed django-tagging, but the problem persists. I also tried running a different project that uses photologue and shares a virtualenv, and I am prompted to perform the same (assumedly destructive) migration.

I can't figure out what could have possibly changed on my system if the problem spans multiple projects and all the dependencies have been freshly installed.

Exception Location: /home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py in raise_field_error, line 1389

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/photologue/photo/add/

Django Version: 1.7.1
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'sortedm2m',
 'photologue',
 'photologue_custom',
 'pornsite')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  584.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  204.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  1454.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  394.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1405.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in save_model
  1046.         obj.save()
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/photologue/models.py" in save
  540.         super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/photologue/models.py" in save
  491.         super(ImageModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  591.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  628.                                    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
  198.             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tagging/fields.py" in _save
  81.             Tag.objects.update_tags(kwargs['instance'], tags)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tagging/models.py" in update_tags
  34.                                         items__object_id=obj.pk))
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  92.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  691.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  709.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1287.         clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1314.                     current_negated=current_negated, connector=connector)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1138.         lookups, parts, reffed_aggregate = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in solve_lookup_type
  1076.         _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in names_to_path
  1383.             self.raise_field_error(opts, name)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in raise_field_error
  1389.                          "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))

Exception Type: FieldError at /admin/photologue/photo/add/
Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword 'items' into field. Choices are: id, name
```

Comment: Have you compared what the migration changed in the db? Have you tried reverting the migration after uninstalling django-tagging? You could also check your tables directly in the sqlite shell `./manage.py dbshell` and see, if there are some "leftovers" ... but if you already created from scratch the sqlite-file again, then probably not.

Comment: I deleted the migrations folder and ran makemigrations again. The models and migrations were made again, and the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to arise from the fact, that django-tagging was somehow still present on the virtualenv.

In your traceback after photologue saves a model, django-tagging reacts to the sent signal and tries to update any related tags:

```
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
  198.             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tagging/fields.py" in _save
  81.             Tag.objects.update_tags(kwargs['instance'], tags)
File "/home/cameron/Envs/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tagging/models.py" in update_tags
  34.                                         items__object_id=obj.pk))
```

There it tries to use the (apparently not existing anymore) field `items`, and that's where the error occurs.

I guess the way you deinstalled django-tagging on the venv didn't really work. Did you uninstalled with: `pip uninstall django-tagging` ?

For reference, here again my comment/steps to recreate the venv

... If your venv is somehow corrupted, the easiest could be to recreate it from scratch:

1. On your venv do:

   `env pip freeze > orig_requirements.txt`

   Check the `orig_requirements.txt` and delete everything you don't need.
2. Make a new venv with no site-packages and reinstall the requirements:

   `mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages photoenv`

   `pip install -r orig_requirements.txt`
3. Now double check you're on this venv when running your django project

   `workon photoenv`

Answer (score 0):

Well the error is simple -- in that you are requesting a field in the database that does not exist. Since you haven't posted code it is hard to be more specific than that. Was one of your templates built, referencing a field named 'items' that is no longer there?

Please edit your question to include a FULL traceback as well as some code where you think the problem could be.

The full traceback will give you a better idea of where the problem is.

Comment: OK, I think part of the problem may be this: I deleted photologue from Env/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages, and when I try to runserver, it tells me there is no module photologue. Fair enough. when I run pip install photologue, it says requirement already satisfied. I suspect it's talking about photologue installed in Env/photologue/lib/python2.7/site-packages, which has a copy of everything in Env/photologue/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (I'm new to Ubuntu so I'm not sure why the filesystem is like that.)

Comment: One question... did you call your venv photologue? Probably it has nothing to do with it, but just to be sure, maybe it could be a good shot to call the venv something else. Some more things to check 1) Are you sure on both site-packages is everything duplicated? Or are those only symlinks? ... (tbc)

Comment: 2) If your venv is somehow corrupted, the easiest could be to recreate it from scratch. Just do on your photologue(?) env `pip freeze > orig_requirements.txt` (maybe check those too, if everything looks fine and delete everything you don't need), then make a new venv with no site-packages: `mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages photoenv` And, if your requirements look good, reinstall them. If not, edit the file until you have only what you need there before installing. `pip install -r orig_requirements.txt`. Now double check you're on this venv when running your django project `workon photoenv`.

Comment: I remade the virtualenv as you suggested and it solved the problem. Again, I can't imagine why this worked because I had previously replaced all the dependencies...makes me wonder what really happened as a learning experience. Thanks

Comment: If you agree, I will elaborate an answer based on the comments above, to make this "official".